How do you copy and paste entire row of source sheet to destination when a date appears in specific column?
I have a worksheet labeled "Key_Combination Management" (Source) that tracks revocation date in Column E:E. I would like to have the entire row that corresponds with that date to be copy and pasted to another worksheet labeled "Revoked Master List" (Destination) whenever a date is entered, then deleted from the source. The code I am currently using allows any time a cell in E:E has data entered to be copy, pasted and deleted. I want to limit to cells that have dates in them.
This is what I am currently using. I am not sure how to make it only execute on cells with dates in E:E on the source sheet.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Range("E:E") Then
        With Target.EntireRow
        .Copy Sheets("Revoked Master List").Cells(Sheets("Revoked Master List").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Delete
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub


Here's one way to handle it:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v, ws As Worksheet, rngDel As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E:E"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'make sure events are not left disabled if there's an error
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Revoked Master List")
    For Each c In rng.Cells        'handling multi-cell updates
        If IsDate(c.Value) Then    'cell has date ?
            c.EntireRow.Copy ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            BuildRange rngDel, c 'add cell to "delete" range
        End If
    Next c
    'any copied rows to delete?
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    
haveError:
    If Err <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Add range `rngAdd` to range `rngTot`
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub

Added - if both source and destination are listobjects then this would work to transfer the rows:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, v, ws As Worksheet, rngDel As Range
    Dim tblSrc As ListObject, tblDest As ListObject
    
    Set tblSrc = Me.ListObjects("SourceTable") 'for example
    
    'has a change occurred in the "RevokeDate" column?
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, _
              tblSrc.ListColumns("RevokeDate").DataBodyRange)
    
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'nothing to handle
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'make sure events are not left disabled if there's an error
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'or use list name: the table to append to
    Set tblDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Revoked Master List").ListObjects(1)
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells        'handling multi-cell updates
        If IsDate(c.Value) Then    'cell has date ?
            Application.Intersect(c.EntireRow, tblSrc.DataBodyRange).Copy _
               tblDest.ListRows.Add().Range
            BuildRange rngDel, c 'add cell to "delete" range
        End If
    Next c
    'any copied rows to delete?
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
    
haveError:
    If Err <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'Add range `rngAdd` to range `rngTot`
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub

It's best to delete all copied rows at the end, and not one by one as you copy them.

Tim, thank you so much. This did exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I appreciate your help!

Is there a way to have it add it to a table instead of a range? The data from the source is pasting in a range under the table on the destination sheet. I can go either way, just wanted to know why it does that, and if there is any pros/cons to having it on a range or a table?

Is the data on the source sheet also in a table?

The source data is in a table, but when it pasted on the destination sheet it was pated into the range underneath the table.

See added code above for dealing with tables/listobjects

Does the source table have to match the actual source sheet? As well as the the table source list column? I received a "Compile error sub or function not defined". It is highlighting the "BuildRange" portion of the code. I tried to update it with the table source list objects to "Key_Combination management" that didn't work, I corrected the name of the table source list column to "Date Revoked" and that didn't work either. There are 4 tables with "Date Revoked" as a column on the source sheet. Are items in a table considered list objects? I can provide a copy of the workbook.

Hey Tim, I tried to include a macro that unprotects the "RevokedMaster" table, run the command then protect "RevokedMaster". I was only able to unprotect then it would add it to the bottom of the table and protect, but only the previous data, not the data that was added while running the sub. I don't understand where I should place the command to protect the table so it includes the newly added row.

Can you edit your question above and add in the exact code you're using?

Would it make more sense to write a new question? I would want someone looking for an answer to this question to see this question and answer as is.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79146425/can-a-destination-table-be-unprotected-and-then-protected-with-the-new-data-ente
